# Is the commission Haram?

Tags: halal-haram

Suppose if I go to shops and offer shop owners some kind of printing service, such as print a bill book, and name card, etc.

Then I go to the printing press and print those items and pay money for it and then sell it back to the shop owners with some profit for me.

Is it Haram or halal?

Is it a type of commission?

Moreover is it good to take part time job?

Comment: No commission is not haram or better not per se!